# How do I fix this issue with my model's texture

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, uv, artifacts

I've recently created a humanoid model to use for animating in the cycles engine, and in the texture view and material view, it looks fine. However in the rendered view, I get strange black spots on my model, i've attached the blend file, if anyone could help me to fix this issue, I would be extremely grateful.
[image]

I've also added the image texture I want to use.[image]

Comment: That's Z fighting. https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=z+fighting. You have two or more faces occupying the same location.

Answer (score 1):

The reason parts of the mesh appear black, is because two vertices are in the same location, and blender renders them as black.

***Deleting the vertices:***
Select the vertices you don't need, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>, and select `Dissolve Vertices`. This will remove the vertices and remove the black overlapping mesh int he Rendered view.

**EDIT:**

***Merging the vertices***
Instead of deleting them, it may be better to merge them. Select two vertices in a similar location, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select `At Center`, if you want to merge the vertices in the middle of both vertices. This will make them into one vertical, without removing any other lines the deleting method would.

Comment: If that was the solution to your problem, please check that this answer solved your problem.